Can we have a canonical question for Ubuntu on Snapdragon processors?
There are multiple questions for Ubuntu on Snapdragon. I found Can you install Ubuntu on a Snapdragon PC? and Ubuntu on snapdragon laptop.
They are not duplicates of Will my device work with Ubuntu? (which tells you to "Try it". But there is no way the standard Ubuntu image can be booted on snapdragon PCs to even try).
I suggest, we choose either of these two questions as the canonical one, and mark the other as duplicate.
Which one would you prefer?

Whichever way it gets closed, this is probably a case where merging is merited. Both answers are basically relying on the same Ubuntu Discourse post for all pertinent information.
